# how to make following jquery function repeat itself

Tags: jquery

This function repeats 2 times i.e when I click on .search-toggle 2 times, z-index of .nav-secondary toggles between 0 and 2. But I want it to toggle in loop without breaking anything. Any help is appreciated.

```
enter code here

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(".search-toggle").click(function() {

$(".nav-secondary").css("z-index",0); 

$(".search-toggle").click (function() {

 $(".nav-secondary").css("z-index",2);

 $(".search-toggle").click(function() {

    $(".nav-secondary").css("z-index",0); 

    $(".search-toggle").click (function() {

      $(".nav-secondary").css("z-index",2);

    });
   });      
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Will this work for you `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    let a;
    (a = $(".nav-secondary")).css("z-index",0); 
    $(".search-toggle").click(function() {
        a.css("z-index", 2-parseInt(a.css("z-index")));
    })
})`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. It does not seem to work. Here I have other piece of code which works fine for making zindex 0, but I can't figure out how to toggle it to original zindex on clicking again on .search-toggle. Here is the code : 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
      $(".search-toggle").click(function() {
      $(".nav-secondary").css("z-index",0);

     }); 
    });

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx Thank you so much. The code just worked. All I had to do is to replace value 0 by 2 and 2 by 0. And now it works fine. You can post the solution in the answer, I'll upvote it. Thanks again, and happy holidays.

Comment: You're welcome. It seems that you want to toggle between 0 and -2 instead of 0 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to toggle the value between 0 and -2.
You can just store the z-index value and invert it when click event fired. Something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    let a; (a = $(".nav-secondary")).css("z-index",2);
    $(".search-toggle").click(function() {
        a.css("z-index", 0-parseInt(a.css("z-index"))); 
    })
})
```

Keep in mind that the toggle value changed after 1 click and switches between 2 and -2